# sending email using java working on netbeans but not on tomcat 8

Tags: java, email, tomcat, netbeans

am workinng on webservice that send emails for costumers,am using netbeans 8.2 as IDE on debian jessie,avery think is working just well ,but when i deploy the web service on tomcat8 web server on a vps am gotting 
    type Exception report

```
message Servlet execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented 
it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/MailLogger
javax.mail.internet.MailDateFormat.<clinit>(MailDateFormat.java:154)
javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.<clinit>(MimeMessage.java:177)
dz.GpsTracker.daoe.DAOEGestionEmailsImp.envoyer(DAOEGestionEmailsImp
.java:42)
dz.GpsTracker.servlets.Inscription.doPost(Inscription.java:167)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.mail.util.MailLogger
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass
(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1294)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass
(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1146)
javax.mail.internet.MailDateFormat.<clinit>(MailDateFormat.java:154)
javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.<clinit>(MimeMessage.java:177)
dz.GpsTracker.daoe.DAOEGestionEmailsImp.envoyer(DAOEGestionEmailsImp.
java:    42)
dz.GpsTracker.servlets.Inscription.doPost(Inscription.java:167)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the 
Apache Tomcat/8.0.14 (Debian) logs.
```

am not using maven

i'v copied java.mail on /usr/share/tomcat8/lib/

i'v java.mail on /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/mywebservice/WEB-INF/classes/dz/mywebservice/lib/

i'v used chmod 777 on java.mail jar

i'have  javax.mail-api-1.6.0.jar and mail.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was that com.sun.mail.util.MailLogger exist in JEE,that for netbeans can run it ,but not tomcat
and the solution is to add javax.mail-1.5.0.jar and u can send email just well